# The right angled triangles ABD and BCD?

Tags: education

AB=5cm BD=4cm and angle ABD=x

Find the exact value of cos(ABC)

this is the trangle...:
https://twitter.com/JxstyBiebs/status/432919494466752514

Answer (score 1):

Use $cos(ABC) = cosxcos90 - sinxsin90$ by sum formula. But $cos90=0$ and $sin90=1$ so we are left with finding $sinx$ which is basic right angle trig. Think of SOHCAHTOA.
My screen shed tears with that J Bieber picture. Next time, please warn us :)

Comment: Ahhhh, I shoulda known that's what I had to do, damn I'm dumb! Thanks man!!! Helped me out loads! Lmao sorry bout that!

Comment: It's a good question though. An upvote, but not for J.B.

Comment: I got the answer, woo! Thanks for ya help! Hahahah nothing wrong with a bit of the biebs ;)